# Beautiful Soup with wikipedia

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wiki, wikipedia, information-retrieval

I'm having trouble making this script work to scrape information from a series of Wikipedia articles.

What I'm trying to do is iterate over a series of wiki URLs and pull out the page links on a wiki portal category (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Electronic_design).

I know that all the wiki pages I'm going through have a page links section. 
However when I try to iterate through them I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wiki_parent.py", line 37, in <module>
    cleaned = pages.get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Why do I get this error?

The file I'm reading in the first part looks like this:

```
1 Category:Abrahamic_mythology
2 Category:Abstraction
3 Category:Academic_disciplines
4 Category:Activism
5 Category:Activists
6 Category:Actors
7 Category:Aerobics
8 Category:Aerospace_engineering
9 Category:Aesthetics
```

and it is stored in a the port_ID dict like so:

> {1: 'Category:Abrahamic_mythology', 2: 'Category:Abstraction', 3: 'Category:Academic_disciplines', 4: 'Category:Activism', 5: 'Category:Activists', 6: 'Category:Actors', 7: 'Category:Aerobics', 8: 'Category:Aerospace_engineering', 9: 'Category:Aesthetics', 10: 'Category:Agnosticism', 11: 'Category:Agriculture'...}

The desired output is:

```
parent_num, page_ID, page_num
```

I realize the code is a little hackish but I'm just trying to get this working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,re,nltk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+'Category:Furniture'

rootdir = '/Users/joshuavaldez/Desktop/L1/en.wikipedia.org/wiki'

reg = re.compile('[\w]+:[\w]+')
number=1
port_ID = {}
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if reg.match(file):
            port_ID[number]=file
            number+=1


test_file = open('test_file.csv', 'w')

for key, value in port_ID.iteritems():

    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+str(value)
    raw = urlopen(url).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(raw)
    pages = soup.find("div" , { "id" : "mw-pages" })
    cleaned = pages.get_text()
    cleaned = cleaned.encode('utf-8')
    pages = cleaned.split('\n')
    pages = pages[4:-2]
    test = test = port_ID.items()[0]

    page_ID = 1
    for item in pages:
        test_file.write('%s %s %s\n' % (test[0],item,page_ID))
        page_ID+=1
    page_ID = 1
```

Comment: Well, at that point in the code, pages is bound to None

Comment: You may want to double-check how you're using soup.find()

Comment: Sorry, I'm a pretty novice coder, but in this context what do you mean by pages being bound to None and is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: @jdv12 Can you give a better example of what you are scraping and a better example of what the desired output should look like?

Answer (score 2):

You are scraping several pages in a loop. But there could be some pages without any `<div id="mw-pages">` tag. So you are getting the `AttributeError` at line,

```
cleaned = pages.get_text()
```

You can use a `if` condition check like:

```
if pages:
    # do stuff
```

Or you can avoid it with a `try-except` block like,

```
try:
    cleaned = pages.get_text()
    # do stuff
except AttributeError as e:
    # do something
```